# Changing attribute values of nodes in a network during breadth first search in R

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph, breadth-first-search

I have created a random (Erdos-Renyi) network that has 100 nodes. I have set an attribute value for all 100 nodes as 0. I find the node with the maximum degree (the most neighbors), and change its attribute value from 0 to 1. Then, using the node as the root node, I do a breadth first search (BFS) on the network.

Here is my code to do this so far:

```
# Loads the igraph package
library(igraph)

# Creates a random (Erdos-Renyi) network with 100 nodes and edges with p = 0.2
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 0.2, type = c("gnp", "gnm"), directed = FALSE, 
    loops = FALSE)

# Sets the attributes of all the nodes to 0
graph <- set.vertex.attribute(graph, "value", value = 0)

# Determines the maximum degree
max_deg <- max(degree(graph))

# The node with the maximum degree becomes the root node for the BFS, and changes
# its value from 0 to 1
root_node <- which(degree(graph) %in% c(max_deg))
V(graph)$value[root_node] = 1 - V(graph)$value[root_node]

# BFS on the network
bfs <- graph.bfs(graph, root = root_node, unreachable = FALSE, order = TRUE,
    dist = TRUE)
```

As it goes through each node of the network, I want it to change the attribute value of the node it's looking at from 0 to 1. I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's looking at"? The BFS "looks at" all vertices that are reachable from the root.

Comment: @GaborCsardi - I want to change the attribute value of the node it's currently looking at, before it moves on to the next node. Would I need to use callback for this? If it can't do this, is there another way to achieve this without using a BFS altogether?

Comment: You cannot change the graph while the BFS is running on it. igraph objects are immutable, like most objects in R.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what you want to do. Can you give an example? What would be the output for your graph?

Comment: Then you don't need to set the attribute at the time when the BFS is "looking at the nodes". Just see `which(is.nan(bfs$dist))`. These are reachable from the root node you chose.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you said, but you can specify multiple root nodes, just specify a vector as `root`. But the multiple BFSes are not performed at the same time. The second is started after the first is over, etc.

Comment: @GaborCsardi - Do you mean like this: `bfs <- graph.bfs(graph, root = c(root_node, root_node2), unreachable = FALSE, order = TRUE, dist = TRUE)`? Also, is there a way to go through all of the nodes in the graph in a BFS type way, but not actually using the BFS function itself? Because I want to look at the neighbors of the first root node, then the neighbors of the second root node, then the neighbors of the first root node's neighbors, then the neighbors of the second root node's neighbors, and so on. Also, the two root nodes are connected in some way (i.e. there is a path between them).

Comment: @ LoneWolf: yes, that's what I mean. The rest I don't understand, sorry. How can you go over the nodes in a BFS way without performing the BFS? Anyway, please show an example, probably in a new question.

Comment: @GaborCsardi - Here is my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667581/changing-attribute-of-nodes-during-breadth-first-search-in-r). Hope this one makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
    if (is.nan(bfs$dist[i]) == FALSE) {
        V(graph)$value[i] = 1 - V(graph)$value[i]
    }
}
```

It basically just checks if a node is connected to the root node. If it is, its attribute value is changed to 1, and if it isn't, then its attribute value remains unchanged.

Comment: **Very** inefficient solution. R has vectors, use them: `V(graph)$value <- ifelse(is.nan(bfs$dist), V(graph)$value, 1-V(graph)$value)`.